# Magento 2 permission issue

Tags: magento2, installation, permissions, apache2

I installed Magento 2 via Composer and after I followed the steps and it was installed I received this on the frontend:
[image]

Basically all URLs go to 404 (admin as well).
I am using Ubuntu 18 and Apache server. This is my virtual host configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    ServerName m2.local
    ServerAlias www.m2.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/magento2>
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        #AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my user, group and permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 magento magento   4096 Okt 21 18:55 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento    138 Okt 17 10:54 auth.json.sample
drwxrwxr-x  2 magento magento   4096 Okt 17 10:54 bin
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento 434977 Okt 17 10:54 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento  12673 Okt 17 10:54 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento 336461 Okt 27 15:37 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento    650 Okt 17 10:54 COPYING.txt
drwxrwxr-x  5 magento magento   4096 Okt 21 18:54 dev
drwxrwxr-x  3 magento magento   4096 Okt 27 15:38 generated
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento     57 Okt 17 10:54 grunt-config.json.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento   2994 Okt 17 10:54 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento   1370 Okt 21 19:01 index.php
drwxrwxr-x  4 magento magento   4096 Okt 21 18:54 lib
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento  10376 Okt 17 10:54 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento  10364 Okt 17 10:54 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento   5495 Okt 17 10:54 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento   1416 Okt 17 10:54 package.json.sample
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento    804 Okt 17 10:54 php.ini.sample
drwxrwxr-x  2 magento magento   4096 Okt 17 10:54 phpserver
drwxrwxr-x  6 magento magento   4096 Okt 17 10:54 pub
-rw-r--r--  1 magento magento      5 Okt 21 18:51 readme.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 magento magento   4191 Okt 17 10:54 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  7 magento magento   4096 Okt 17 10:54 setup
drwxrwxrwx  6 magento magento   4096 Okt 27 15:38 var
drwxrwxr-x 60 magento magento   4096 Okt 27 15:37 vendor
```

Also I followed up the permissions from the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html):

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} +
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Can someone give me an idea what I should try?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. 
The mod_rewrite module was enabled. To check if it is enabled, you can use `phpinfo()`. 
To enable just use this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
systemctl restart apache2
```